# removing duplicate integers from an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on a program that removes duplicate values from an array by ordering it and then removing duplicate, consecutive values. First I execute a selection sort sorting method, and then call a function `removedup()` that modifies the array and returns the size. Then I basically print the values in the array up to that size. However, when I execute it, it only prints the original array and then a bunch of blank space. Does anyone know why this is occurring?

My code: http://pastebin.com/uTTnnMHN

Just the de-duplication code:

```
int removedup(int a[])
{
    int i, count, j;
    count = n;
    for (i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {
        if (a[i] == a[i + 1]) {
            for (j = 0; j < (n - i); j++) {
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
            }
            count--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest debugging the pieces individually. Make sure the output routine works. Make sure the sorting routine works. Make sure the de-dup routine works. (That one looks sketchiest to me..)

Comment: I had to replace your GetInteger routine with scanf, but once I did, the sorted array printed fine; however, it never returned from removedup if there were any duplicates.  What happens if you print out your array BEFORE you sort it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm: efficient way to remove duplicate integers from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532819/algorithm-efficient-way-to-remove-duplicate-integers-from-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

-1    for(j=0;j<(n-i);j++)

Is your loop to shift left your array (thus removing the duplicate value), j should not be init to j but to i, and the condition does not seem right

A correct one could be:

```
for(j=i;j<n-1;j++)
{
   a[j]=a[j+1];
}
a[n-1] = 0; // Because you shift your table to the left, the last value should not be used
```

Answer (score 1):

first if i=0 and if  a[i]==a[i+1] then i=-1

```
for(i=0;i<(n-1);i++)
 {
      if(a[i]==a[i+1])
      {                       
          for(j=0;j<(n-i);j++)
          {
              a[j]=a[j+1];
          }
          count--;
          i--;  //i=-1  if(a[i]==a[i+1]) && if(i==0)
      }
 }
```

Comment: but then it would be +1 before the next loop so then it would = 0, right?

Answer (score 1):

In your duplicate removal function, you need to start the moving loop at `i`, as has been mentioned, and you must use `count - 1` as the loop bound for both loops, otherwise you will have an infinite loop whenever there are duplicates, because then `a[n-2] == a[n-1]` always after the first moving loop.

```
int removedup(int a[])
{
    int i, count, j;
    count = n;
    for(i = 0; i < (count-1); i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == a[i+1])
        {

            for(j = i; j < (count-1); j++)
            {
                a[j]=a[j+1];
            }
            count--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

works correctly.

Comment: But count represents the size of the modified array. If I decrease it inside the loop every time, that wouldn't be accurate, since it goes n-i times just to move every value?

Comment: Decrementing it every time you have shifted the 'tail' of the array after a duplicate has been found is the right thing, because you morally remove one element from the array, so it becomes one shorter. And both loops should stop at the number of elements currently in the array.

Comment: Do you mean decrementing it within the if statement like this? http://pastebin.com/SsBRL25B

Comment: Close. The upper bounds of the loops have to be adjusted so the 'removed' part of the array is ignored, see updated answer. Setting the last entry to 0 doesn't help.

Comment: I see what you mean now, ok. The only issue I'm having now is that it seems to be skipping the last few integers - e.g. if I enter < 50, 60, 70, 70, 72, 80, 85, 85, 90, 100 > it doesn't print 90 and 100. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes. Because there was a typo I didn't see. In the inner loop, the upper bound was `count - i` instead of `count - 1`. Corrected now.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that, fixed it and the program seems to be working now. Thank you very much for your help Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating another array anyway, why not simplify your function?

```
int removedup(int a[], int b[])
{
    int i;
    int count = 1;
    b[0] = a[0]


    for(i=1;i<(n-1);i++){
        if(a[i-1] != a[i]){
            b[count++] = a[i];
        }
    }
    return count;                          
}
```

Then when you call the function,

```
count=removedup(a, OutArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int removedup(int a[])
{
    int i;
    count = n;
    for (i = 0; i < (count-1); ++i) {
        if (a[i] == a[i+1]) { /* found a duplicate */
            int d = 0; /* count the duplicates */
            do {
                ++d;
            } while ((i+1+d) < count && a[i] == a[i+1+d]); /* probe ahead again for a duplicate */

            /* at this point we have either run out of duplicates or hit the end of the array */
            if ((i+1+d) < count)
                memmove(&a[i+1], &a[i+1+d], sizeof(int)*(count-(i+1+d))); /* shift down rest of the array if there's still elements to look at */ 
            count -= d; /* adjust the count down by the number of duplicates */
        }
    }
    return count;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this one,without sort but traverse.finally print the effective values of the array and return its size.

```
int removedup(int a[])
{
    int i, count, j;
    count = n;
    int b[n];
    memset(b,0,sizeof(b));
    for (i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) 
    {
        if (-1 != b[i])
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<n-1;j++)
            {
                if( a[i]==a[j])
                {
                    b[j]=-1;
                    count--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(-1 != b[i])
        {
            printf("%d ",a[i]);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```