# How to count distinct values in a list in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, list, count, complexity-theory, distinct-values

I can think of sorting them and then going over each element one by one but this is nlogn. Is there a linear method to count distinct elements in a list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update: - distinct vs. unique**

---

If you are looking for **"unique"** values (As in if you see an element "JASON" more than once, than it is no longer unique and should not be counted)

You can do that in linear time by using a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) ;)

(The generalized / language-agnostic idea is [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table))

Each entry of a HashMap / Hash table is `<KEY, VALUE>` pair where the keys are unique (but no restrictions on their corresponding value in the pair)

**Step 1:**

Iterate through all elements in the list once: **O(n)**

- For each element seen in the list, check to see if it's in the HashMap already **O(1), amortized**

  - If not, add it to the HashMap with the value of the element in the list as the KEY, and the number of times you've seen this value so far as the VALUE **O(1)**
  - If so, increment the number of times you've seen this KEY so far **O(1)**

**Step2:**

Iterate through the HashMap and count the KEYS with VALUE equal to exactly 1 (thus unique) **O(n)**

**Analysis:**

- Runtime: O(n), amortized
- Space: O(U), where U is the number of distinct values.

---

If, however, you are looking for **"distinct"** values (As in if you want to count how many *different* elements there are), use a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead of a HashMap / Hash table, and then simply query the size of the HashSet.

Comment: This is how to find a number of unique values in the list and the question is about finding a number of distinct values. To count distinct values use [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). Just add every element of the list to the HashSet and check its cardinality.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to count ALL the values in the HashMap in step 2, rather than just those with value 1? Doing it this way would only count the elements that appear exactly once, eg. the list {PAT, PAT, STEVE, JOEL} would result in a value of 2 (only STEVE and JOEL occur once) rather than the correct value of 3 distinct names.

Comment: Note! There is an interpretation discrepancy here: My assumption is that if you see a particular value 2 or more times, it is no longer "distinct" / "unique" - but I'll edit that in to be more clear.

Comment: so since this algorithm is amortized, it does not guarantee O(n) right? It could well have a worst case runtime of O(n2)?

Comment: @polerto With any reasonable implementation of HashMap / Hashtable (such as the ones from Java libs) you can assume `O(n)` runtime.

Comment: You can't do that in linear time with HashMap, because there may exist collisions. With collisions, then even the lookup in the map may have complexity `O(n)`, if every object has the same hash value.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt [this extremely cool O(n)-time **and O(1)-space** in-place algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533667/47984) for removing duplicates to the task of counting distinct values -- simply count the number of values equal to the sentinel value in a final O(n) pass, and subtract that from the size of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Add every element of the list to a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and then check the [size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#size%28%29) (cardinality) of the HashSet, which is the number of distinct values in the list.