# Ruby : Eliminate duplicates in an array without using .uniq

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an Array that contains

`arrTV = ['Thor: The Dark World', 'Ender's Game', 'Jackass Presents: Bad Grandpa', 'Last Vegas', 'Free Birds', 'Free Birds' ]`

The last two elements are duplicates. I want to loop through the array and check if there exists a duplicate and I do not want to use `.uniq`

Please advice

I have tried something like this and it doesn't work

```
arrTV.each do |i|
  count = 0

  #if arrTV[i] == arrTV[i+1]
  #  puts "equal"
  #  count = count + 1
  #
  #end
  #puts count

  #if arrTV[i] = arrTV[i+1]
  #arrTV.delete_at(i+1)
  #end

end
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `uniq`?

Comment: There's some interesting solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532819/algorithm-efficient-way-to-remove-duplicate-integers-from-an-array

Comment: Below you posted a comment "...I then used arrTV.uniq, but that too didn't take off the duplicates.". You posted that well after @Michael posted his answer, in which he pointed out that you must escape all apostrophes, in particular, `'Ender\'s Game'`. Did you do that? If not, that explains a lot. Once that's done, I guarantee uniq will work. Alternatively, you could change all the single quotes to double quotes, except for the apostrophes (`"Ender's Game"). I recommend you do it that way. It only has to be done for words containing apostrophes, but better to do it for all.

Answer (score 3):

This is not likely the most efficient, but it's easy to understand at a high level what is going on.

```
require 'set'

arrTV = ['Thor: The Dark World', 'Ender's Game', 'Jackass Presents: Bad Grandpa', 'Last Vegas', 'Free Birds', 'Free Birds' ]

arrTV.to_set.to_a
```

Comment: AFAIK this is really the old "convert it to a Hash and extract they keys" trick in disguise. Probably more efficient than you think it is.

Comment: I agree, `set` is probably quite efficient.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
2.0.0-p247 :004 > arrTV = ['Thor: The Dark World', 'Ender\'s Game', 
'Jackass Presents: Bad Grandpa', 'Last Vegas', 'Free Birds', 'Free Birds' ]  
# (Note escaping the `'` in Ender`'`s)

2.0.0-p247 :009 > prev='xxxxx'
2.0.0-p247 :009 > new_array=[]

2.0.0-p247 :016 > arrTV.sort.each do |current|
2.0.0-p247 :017 >     if (current != prev)
2.0.0-p247 :018?>       new_array << current
2.0.0-p247 :018?>       puts current
2.0.0-p247 :019?>       prev=current
2.0.0-p247 :020?>     end
2.0.0-p247 :021?>   end
Ender's Game
Free Birds
Jackass Presents: Bad Grandpa
Last Vegas
Thor: The Dark World
```

Comment: i see the following error msg:       comparison of String with Array failed (ArgumentError)
      ./features/feature_list/calabash_android_helper.rb:347:in `sort'
      ./features/feature_list/calabash_android_helper.rb:347:in `getSubHeader'
      ./features/feature_list/now_playing.rb:45:in `getSubHeaderList'
      ./features/step_definitions/nowPlaying_steps.rb:45:in `/^I should see list of SubHeader$/'
      features/box_office.feature:13:in `Then I should see list of SubHeader'

Comment: huh? I tried this is 1.9.3 and it worked there too.  You are posting results from running spec files. You should post that too.

Comment: Hi Michael !! Thanks for your Time.. The Flow is as follows .. Cucumber : Then i Should See a list of Movies

Comment: Step Definition : def getSubHeader

    sleep(1)
    q = query("TextView marked:'Ratings'") # Boundary condition, this element is visible only after scrolled to bottom  

    arrTV = Array.new(query("TextView id:'movieTitle'", :text))


    while q.empty?
      performAction('scroll_down')
      sleep(1)
      if element_exists("TextView")
        arrTV.push(query("TextView id:'movieTitle'", :text))
      end

      q = query("TextView marked:'Ratings'")

    end

    arrTV = arrTV.uniq
    puts arrTV.size
    puts arrTV


  end

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
arr = []
arrTV.each do |e|
     arr << e unless arr.include?(e)
end
#arr should now contains the same elements as arrTV.uniq does.
```

But then, why not use `uniq`? Homework maybe?

Comment: arr << e unless arr.include?(e)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [*`Array#|`*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-7C) method, if you don't want to use [*`Array#uniq`*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) method.

```
arr = %w(foo bar baz bar)
(arr | arr)
# => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I will confine my remarks to your last sentence:  "Where am I going wrong?"

```
arrTV = ['Thor: The Dark World', 'Ender's Game', 'Jackass Presents: Bad Grandpa', \
         'Last Vegas', 'Free Birds', 'Free Birds' ]
```

[Edit: As @Michael pointed out, you **must** escape all apostrophes in the elements of `arrTV` (in particular, `'Ender\'s Game'`).  Alternatively, you can can enclose the strings in double quotes:

```
arrTV = ["Thor: The Dark World", "Ender's Game", "Jackass Presents: Bad Grandpa", \
         "Last Vegas", "Free Birds", "Free Birds" ]
```

I would recommend doing the latter.  End of Edit]

It appears you first tried this:

```
arrTV.each do |i|
  count = 0
  if arrTV[i] == arrTV[i+1]
    puts "equal"
    count = count + 1
  end
  puts count
end
```

The first time through the (`do..end`) block, `i` is set equal to the first element of `arrTV`, which is `'Thor: The Dark World'`, so you are attempting to execute

```
  if arrTV['Thor: The Dark World'] == arrTV['Thor: The Dark World'+1]
```

which will raise an error.  Consider doing this instead

```
  if arrTV[count] == arrTV[count+1]
```

Better, but there are still a couple of problems.  Firstly, every time the block is passed to an element of `arrTV`, `count` is reset to zero.  You can fix that by moving `count = 0` before `arrTV.delete_at(i+1)`.  Also, move `puts count` to the end of the `if` statement (right before `end`).

Secondly, what happens when `count = 5`?  At that point you are executing

```
  if arrTV[5] == arrTV[6],
```

but `arrTV` only contains 6 elements, the last one indexed `5`. `arrTV[6]` is not defined.  There are many ways to fix this problem.  One is to add:

```
  break if count == 5
```

after

```
  count = count + 1
```

It looks like you next tried to do this within the block

```
   if arrTV[i] = arrTV[i+1]
   arrTV.delete_at(i+1)
```

(Incidentally, notice that you want `==`, not `=` in the first statement.)  Even if we replace `i` with count, you are attempting to delete some elements of `arrTV` while interating over it.  That's a no-no.  What you need to do is start with this:

```
  (0..arrTV.size-2) each do |i|
```

with this, you no longer need `count`.  Nor do you need to break out of the loop once you've processed the next-to-last element of `arrTV`.  More importantly, since you are not iterating over the elements of `arrTV`, you can delete them within the loop:

```
   arrTV.delete_at(i+1)
```

(This way, you could also add elements to `arrTV`, or modify elements.) I will leave it to you to fix it from here.  I would like to point out, however, that the approach you are taking will only eliminate duplicates if they are adjacent elements of `arrTV`.  If order is unimportant, you need to modify your approach.

Lastly, one Ruby convention is to use only lower case letters for variable names, and to add underscores where necessary for readability.  You might use something like `arr_tv`, rather than `arrTV`.

Comment: Hi All,

Thanks for your response. I am new to ruby.

I am working with a tool to automate android app. The tool is called calabsh. Now, I scrolled one screen of the app from top to bottom to get a list of movies on the screen. 

I got the following list of elements into an array arrTV. I then used arrTV.uniq, but that too didnt take off the duplicates. I then used arrTV.length, arrTV.size, arrTV.count ..all returned 14 instead of 51
So I am using .uniq.. and nothing works. So thought of working on the elements in the array and take off duplicates.

Comment: The Array contains : Thor: The Dark World
Ender's Game
Jackass Presents: Bad Grandpa
Last Vegas
Free Birds
Free Birds
Gravity
Captain Phillips
12 Years a Slave
Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs 2
The Counselor
The Counselor
Carrie
Escape Plan
Enough Said
Insidious: Chapter 2
Prisoners
Prisoners
We're The Millers
Baggage Claim
Planes
Rush
Percy Jackson: Sea of Monsters
Percy Jackson: Sea of Monsters
I'm In Love With A Church Girl
Lee Daniels' The Butler
Runner Runner
Krrish 3
Don Jon
Don Jon
About Time
Instructions Not Included
The Mortal Instruments: City of Bones
All Is Lost
Machete Kills

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Set Intersection method with the Ampersand (`&`) Operator :

```
arrTV = ['Thor: The Dark World', 'Ender\'s Game', 
'Jackass Presents: Bad Grandpa', 'Last Vegas', 'Free Birds', 'Free Birds' ] 

def unique(array)
  array & array
end

result = unique(arrTV)
print result # => ["Thor: The Dark World", "Ender's Game", "Jackass Presents: Bad Grandpa", "Last Vegas", "Free Birds"]
```

With [Set Intersection](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) (using Intersect Operator `&`), a new array is returned containing elements common to the two arrays, with duplicates removed.

In the method, the `&` is placed between the two arrays we want to evaluate. In this example, we pass one array into the method but evaluate that array against itself to remove any duplicates.