# lower bound of counting unique integers in a Linked list

Tags: algorithm

okay,so i was searching around the web and trying out for my self and yet i could'nt get the answer

what is the lower bound for counting the number of unique integers in a linked list(a list in particular and not an array)

it seems like the lower bound is O(nLogN) time complexity and O(1) space complexity.

or O(n) times complexity and O(n) space complexity.

is there an O(n) times complexity with O(1) space complexity??
and would your answer change upon switching it from a list to an array?

-- 
just to be clear,here's an example:
{1,4,2,20,2,1,1}
the number of unique items is 2 - {4,20}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532819/algorithm-efficient-way-to-remove-duplicate-integers-from-an-array/1533667#1533667

Comment: When you think that list|array is such a  big deal then better be clear about what kind of list.

Comment: i've seen his answer,though he writes "It's guaranteed to be O(1) in axillary space (the recursion is a tail call), and is typically O(N) time complexity." , i want to know if exists a worst case O(N),not just typically

Comment: How do you remove dupes in a linked list in O(n log n) time and O(1) space? It seems impossible to me.

Comment: inplace marge sort(no auxillaries are needed in a linked list),and then just traversing the list removing dupes

Comment: Doesn't merge sort require O(log n) space for the call stack?

Comment: technically you are correct,but i ignored the space used by the recursion call for that matter.